# How to send bearer token as parameter and retrieve it in another screen in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to send bearer token as parameter from one screen and retrieve it another screen and send it too sidebar.

Login.js where i have saved bearer token in const usertoken but can't figure out how to sent it as parameter

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button,Text,View,Image,TextInput,SafeAreaView,ImageBackground,Alert} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {

super(props)

this.state = {

UserName: '',
UserPassword: ''

}

}

UserLoginFunction = () =>{

const { UserName }  = this.state ;
const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;


fetch('https://api.idepoz.com/ncl/api/login', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({

    username: UserName,

    password: UserPassword

})

}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        //console.log(responseJson);
        
        if(responseJson)
        {
        const usertoken =  responseJson.token;    
        this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'QrScan'});

        }
        else{

            Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        });

        }

        
        }
```

The following is the screen where i want to retrieve the parameter and navigate it to sidebar

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Container, Header, Title, Drawer, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Text } from 'native-base';
    import { Alert } from 'react-native';
    import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import SideBar from './components/SideBar';

    export default class QrScan extends React.Component{
    closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close();
    }
    openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open();
    }
    render()
    {
    return(
    <Drawer
    ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
    content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}/>}
    onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Left>
                    <Button transparent onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}>
                        <MaterialIcons name="list" size={40} color="#FFFFFF" />
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                    <Title></Title>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                <Button transparent>
                    <Ionicons  name="search" size={40} color="#FFFFFF" onPress={() => Alert.alert('Search Button pressed')} />
                </Button>   
                </Right>
            </Header>
            <Content>
                <Text>
                    
                </Text>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    </Drawer>
    );
    }
    }
```

This is the sidebar.js where i want to retrieve the token and use it to logout

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
    import { Drawer,Container, Content, Header, Right, Button } from 'native-base';
    import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 


    export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
    <Container>
        <Header>
        <Right>
            <Button transparent>
                <FontAwesome  name="close" size={24} color="#FFFFFF" onPress={() => this.props.closeDrawer()} />
            </Button>   
        </Right>
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <Button transparent>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>Log Out</Text>       
        </Button> 
        </Content>
    </Container>
    );
    }
    }
```

This is a expo project and i am using react navigation 4.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redux for sharing data from one component to another

https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, In Login.js I stored the bearer token inside UserLoginFunction

```
UserLoginFunction = () =>{

    const { UserName }  = this.state ;
    const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;
    
    
    fetch('https://api.idepoz.com/ncl/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    
        username: UserName,
    
        password: UserPassword
    
    })
    
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if(responseJson)
            {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('QrScan',{usertoken:responseJson.token});
            }
            else{
    
                Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }
    
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });

}
```

In qrscan.js i retrieved the bearer token like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        token: ''
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        token: this.props.navigation.state.params.usertoken,
    })
}
```

Then i send the token again to sidebar like this inside render

```
render()
{
    // const authtoken= this.props.navigation.getParam('usertoken');
    //console.log(this.state.token);
    return(
        <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} usertoken={this.state.token} />}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
            <Container>
            </Container>
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

I retrieved the bearer token in sidebar like this

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.usertoken);
    return ()
}
```